# Cucumber Puppeteer: error trying to call step function with arguments

Tags: cucumber, puppeteer, cucumberjs

Below is code where I try to include arguments in a Then statement (last line) when I am calling a step function
I get an error message stating invalid third argument.
So how do I pass parameters to the function?

```
async function confirmSheetCreated(folderName,sheetName) {
    await this.page.waitFor(1500);
    let sheetExists=await this.sheetExists(folderName,sheetName)
    await this.page.isTrue(sheetExists);
}



When('I click plus button in top menu', { timeout: 5*1000 }, clickAddSheet);
When('I click Sheet option in dropdown', { timeout: 5*1000 }, clickSelectSheet);
When('I fill in New Sheet Lookup dialog', { timeout: 5*1000 },fillNewLookupSheetDialog);
When('I click Create New Sheet button',{ timeout: 5*1000 },clickCreateNewSheet);
Then( 'I confirm new sheet created',{ timeout: 5*1000 },  confirmSheetCreated('Revenue','Test Sheet 1'));
```

Comment: You're assigning the result of the function as a step definition, not the function itself. Also, your step doesn't yield any arguments to the function so that will be an error too.

Comment: Please explain how I can call confirmSheetCreated with different parameters  so that I don't have to have different functions with hardcoded folderName and SheetName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that the parameters are created in the cucumber feature file by putting the values in quotes like this:
I confirm "Test Sheet 1" created in the "Revenue" folder

Then in the step you enter placeholders like this:

```
    Then ('I confirm {string} created in the {string} folder,{timeout:5*1000},confirmSheetCreated);
```

and finally the function looks like this:

```
async function confirmSheetCreated(sheetName, folderName) {
    await this.page.waitFor(1500);
    let sheetExists=await this.sheetExists(folderName,sheetName)
    await this.page.isTrue(sheetExists);
}
```

The first string becames the sheet name, and the second the Folder.